# How to have a space between prompt and input in java?

Tags: java, shell, command, prompt

I am writing a program and one of the requirements is that when running the program in command prompt or any other terminal, there needs to be a space before the user input, for example:

c:\users\person\documents> input      good

vs

c:\users\person\documents>input       bad

Basically there needs to be a space in between $ and the input. ($ would be for unix terminals I think, and for windows it's >).

I was trying to use System.out.print statements but I'm having the feeling that's not the way to do it at all. Thanks.

Comment: In order to collect user input you need to prompt the user for input. i.e. Enter your name: 

Otherwise how do they know what to do? So when you prompt the user put a space after the colon. Then use a Scanner object to read the input.

Comment: Print a space character?

Comment: `System.out.print (" ");`